# Aborted(core dumped)

Tags: c++, malloc

I write a program about graph(in Data Structure), when I finish coding, I compiled it successfullly, but when I run the .out file, it turns out these

```
razrlele@razrlele-ThinkPad:~/work/ds$ ./graph
graph: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)-       >bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have never encouter this kind of error, how can I deal with it?
Here is my codes:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20

typedef struct graph
{
    char v[MAX+1]; //the mark of each vertex
    int vexnum, arcnum; //the number of vertex and arc
    int w[MAX+1][MAX+1]; //matrix with weight of each arc
}*wgraph;

typedef struct stack
{
    char v[MAX+1];
    int len;
}*wstack; //stack used to calculate the path
wstack sc;
wstack way;
void creategraph(wgraph &M);
void build(wstack &s);
void clear(wstack &s);

void push(wstack &s, char e);
char pop(wstack &s);
int locate(wgraph M, char e);
int In(wstack s, char e);

void show(wgraph M, wstack s);
int compute(wgraph M, wstack s);
void compare(wgraph M, wstack &s1, wstack &s2);
void calculate(wgraph &M, int i, int j);

int main()
{
    char a,b;
    int key;
    wgraph M;

    build(sc);
    build(way);
    creategraph(M);
    while(1)
    {
        clear(sc);
        clear(way);
        cout<<"What would you like?"<<endl
            <<"1. Find a best path"<<endl
            <<"0. Exit"<<endl;
        cin>>key;
        switch(key)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Please input two vertexs:"<<endl;
                cin>>a>>b;
                calculate(M, locate(M, a), locate(M, b));
                break;
            case 0:
                cout<<"Thank you, ByeBye!";
                return 0;
        }
    return 0;
    }
}

void creategraph(wgraph &M)
{
    int i, j, weight ;
    char p1, p2;
    M = (wgraph )malloc(sizeof(wgraph));
    cout<<"Please input the number of vertex and arc"<<endl;
    cin>>M->vexnum>>M->arcnum;
    for(i = 1; i <= M->vexnum; i++)
     for(j = 1; j <= M->vexnum; j++)
     {
        if(i == j) M->w[i][j] = 0;
        else M->w[i][j] = -1;
    } // initiate the matrix
    cout<<"Vertex: "<<M->vexnum<<" Arc: "<<M->arcnum<<endl;
    cout<<"PLease input the mark of each vertex"<<endl;
    for(i = 1; i <= M->vexnum; i++)
        cin>>M->v[i];
    for(i = 1; i <= M->vexnum; i++)
        cout<<M->v[i];
    cout<<endl<<"please in put each arc like: a b 4"<<endl;
    for(i = 1; i <= M->arcnum; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please input the "<<i<<" data"<<endl;
        cin>>p1>>p2;
        M->w[locate(M, p1)][locate(M, p2)] = weight;
        M->w[locate(M, p2)][locate(M, p1)] = weight;
    }
}//creategraph

void build(wstack &s)
{
    s = (wstack )malloc(sizeof(wstack));
    s->len = 0;
}//build

void clear(wstack &s)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= s->len; i++)
    s->v[i] = '\0';
    s->len = 0;
}//clear

void push(wstack &s, char e)
{
    if(s->len <= MAX)
    s->v[++s->len] = e;
}//push

char pop(wstack &s)
{
    if(s->len > 0)
    return s->v[s->len--];
    return 0;
}//pop

int locate(wgraph M, char e) //locate the position of each vertex 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= M->vexnum; i++)
    if( e == M->v[i]) return i;
}
int In(wstack s, char e)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= s->len; i++)
    if (s->v[i] == e) return 1;
    return 0;
}//In

void show(wgraph M, wstack s)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i<=s->len; i++)
        cout<<s->v[i];
    cout<<'\t'<<compute(M, s)<<endl;
}//show

int compute(wgraph M, wstack s)
{
    int sum = 0, i;
    for(i = 1; i < s->len; i++)
    sum += M->w[locate(M, s->v[i])][locate(M, s->v[i+1])];
    return sum;
}//compute

void compare(wgraph M, wstack &s1, wstack &s2)
{
    int i;
    if(compute(M, s2) == 0 || compute(M, s2) > compute(M, s1))
    for(i = 1; i <= s1->len; i++)
    s2->v[i] = s1->v[i];
    s2->len = s2->len;
}//compare

void calculate(wgraph &M, int i, int j)
{
    int k;
    push(sc, M->v[i]);
    for(k = 0; k < M->vexnum; k++)
    {
    if((In(sc, M->v[k]) && k != j|| M->w[i][k] <= 0))
     continue; // skip two points where there is no arch
            else if(k != j)
            calculate(M, k, j);
            else if(k == j && sc->len == M->vexnum)
                {
                push(sc, M->v[k]);
                show(M, sc);
                compare(M, sc, way);
                pop(sc);
                }
    }
    pop(sc);
}
```

Comment: What about firing up a debugger and check where it came from in your code? Or step through line by line and see where exactly it fails.

Comment: For a C++ program you don't use much of the features available in C++, it's more like a C program with a few `cin` and `cout` as almost the only C++ functionality you use.

Comment: Why are yuo not using `new` instead of `malloc`

Comment: @EdHeal  yep, I replace it, really better ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
s = (wstack )malloc(sizeof(wstack));
```

will only allocate enough for a `wstack`, which is a pointer. This will only allocate 4 bytes on most systems. You need to use

```
s = (wstack )malloc(sizeof(stack));
```

to allocate the right amount

Comment: It works!!Thanks so much!!! But I am wondering why there is nothing wrong with
    
    `M = (wgraph )malloc(sizeof(wgraph));`

Comment: @razrLeLe - Still should use `new`

Comment: @razrLeLe Because it's [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and one can't really say what will happen with code containing undefined behavior.

Comment: @razrLeLe there is something wrong with that, it has the same problem. @EdHeal - I agree - `new` is the right way to do it here.

Comment: @TheDark thx, having replaced it ;-)